# image uploading ok locally but on server Unable to load the web page because the server sent no data

Tags: php, webserver, image-uploading

I have php file uploading module
works fine for any size of image
but when I uploaded it to server
it is still woking for small images about upto 1MB
but for large files chrome says
 Unable to load the web page because the server sent no data.
and about same in other browsers
and it also takes long
i have also filtered max_size and set to 5MB

Comment: What do you mean by "i have also filtered max_size" ?

Comment: And _please_ stop using terms like "please help" in questions.

Comment: I have restricted max_files_size to 5mb, not larger, i mean less than 5mb are allowed

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase *two* php settings: `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`

Depending on your php version the settings might have slightly different names.